# Insert statement after CTE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an insert statement after a cte expression as below

```
WITH d as 
(Select t1,t2 from test)

Insert into test2 (t1,t2) select t1,t2 from d
```

This expression works fine when I run this as a query, but I need to create a view for this and when I use it in view I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'"  What could be the issue?

Comment: you can't create a view over an insert statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a view over the query you're feeding to insert, use this:

```
CREATE VIEW
        myview
AS
WITH    d as 
        (
        SELECT  t1, t2
        FROM    test
        )
SELECT  t1, t2
FROM    d
```

You can then use the view as a source to `INSERT` as you would any other table:

```
INSERT
INTO    test2 (t1, t2)
SELECT  *
FROM    myview
```

Answer (score 1):

In RDBMS you have statements for *doing* something

- insert
- delete
- alter
- create
- ...

You can put them into `Stored Procedure` or `Trigger`

Other actions are *read-only*

- select

You can put this into `View` or `Function`

A `VIEW` is a name for a stored `SELECT`. You cannot change anything there...